# (HBase) Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, java-home

I have read some comments about setting JAVA_HOME. As I am a beginner in this,I did not edit anything without any knowledge of what I was doing. I did not want to mess things up more than this.
So if you can guide me through this and tell me what is wrong with my coding, I would really appreciate it.

I have been trying to install Hadoop and then HBase. After a lot of difficulties and error solving, I could finally install Hadoop, and get the this output when I ran `start-all.sh` and everything seemed to be fine.

```
> hduser@CSLAP106:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh

> hduser@CSLAP106:~$ jps

> 3005 NameNode

> 3404 JobTracker

> 5570 Jps

> 3554 TaskTracker

> 3311 SecondaryNameNode
```

I also have this Java Version and when I type `echo JAVA_HOME`, I get this output:

```
> hduser@CSLAP106:~$ java -version 
> 
> java version "1.7.0_25" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12)
> (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)   OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed
> mode) 
> hduser@CSLAP106:~$ echo JAVA_HOME JAVA_HOME
```

After this, I tried to install HBase (which I think I am about to give up on), and constantly I get the error that `JAVA_HOME is not set and java cannot be found`

This is what I tried to start Hbase:

```
hduser@CSLAP106:~$ /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/start-hbase.sh
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
| NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
|       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
+======================================================================+
```

I also check in this directory `/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin` to see if it recognizes Java or not, and it does!

After searching through Strackoverflow and other people's answers to the same problem, I tried to apply them to my .xml and .sh files, but again nothing happened.

**For HADOOP**

this is the `hadoop-env.sh` in which I set the JAVA_HOME:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

This is the editing for `my $HOME/.bashrc` :

```
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386

# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

**For HBase**

These are the edits I have made in `hbase-site.xml`

```
<property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310 /hbase</value>
</property>
```

This is for the `hbase-env.sh`

```
# The java implementation to use.  Java 1.6 required.
# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
```

This is all I guess.

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386` in `hbase-env.sh` is outcommented?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: By out-commented, what do you mean? I think the first time I read your comment, I got it wrong. I thought you meant I should have added ' # ' to that comment, and when I did it, I started to receive error! So I guess you meant something esle by 'outcommented' that I did not quite get!

Comment: I meant that the row that is `# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386` should not have an startint `#` and be `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386` instead!

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: THANK YOU VERY MUCH DAVID! That solved my problem. HBase just launched, however, it did not give me the `H Master` I was looking for when I typed `JPS`. It shows  `starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.out
/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 150: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script as root?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: I run the script with the  `hduser` and when I want to execute the `sh` file, it gives me a `permission denied` error . I will copy the error I get:  `starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.out`- `/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 150: /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.log: Permission denied`- `head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-CSLAP106.out’ for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try running the script with `sudo sh ./script.sh`!

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: It says: `The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established` - `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes` It requires the **localhost** password. what is the password for it? (Sorry if my questions are stupid, I'm new in this completely. I really appreciate your help.)

Comment: Not really sure, did you try leaving it empty? Or maybe try "admin" or "localhost"

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: I tried **admin**, **localhost**, and left it empty. It did not work. `root@localhost's password: - localhost: Permission denied, please try again.` - `localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).` - `starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-CSLAP106.out` - But it does not log in to master, and again asks for a password

Comment: Is it your computer? Or what computer is it you're logged in on?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: It is my work place computer, but the admin is set to be me

Comment: Guess I really cant help you anymore.. Isnt there anyone at your workplace that can help you with this?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf: Unfortunately, nope :( ... But thank you soooo very much for you help and patience. :) Maybe I can ask this as a new thread in the forum.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the HBase could not find JAVA_HOME and java binary although you can run `java -version` locally.

You should run `export JAVA_HOME=/the/path/of/you/jdk/` before running HBase.

BTY, `echo JAVA_HOME JAVA_HOME` is incorrect. You may want `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 4):

Hbase tries to read JAVA_HOME directory set on hbase-env.sh file.

In hbase-env.sh file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/ is set and commented.
```

Default JAVA_HOME set for hbase.

If you set java home in different directory please edit the line and comment out it.

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below:

"Java needs to be installed and available. If you get an error indicating that Java is not installed, but it is on your system, perhaps in a non-standard location, edit the conf/hbase-env.sh file and modify the JAVA_HOME setting to point to the directory that contains bin/java your system."

The link is http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set JAVA_HOME path in ~/.bashrc file and still Hbase is giving the same error of "JAVA_HOME not found", set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment file.

I face this issue and it worked for me when i set JAVA_HOME in '/etc/environment'

Answer (score 1):

Just modify `hbase-env.sh` like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/your/java/path
```

I don't know why `/etc/profile` java path doesn't work, but this way would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the JAVA home -> you can do this two ways

Either set the path in hbase-env.sh in ~/hbase-0.98.10-hadoop1/conf JAVA_HOME = 'PATH/TO/JAVE_HOME'

OR in terminal under sudo execute user$ export JAVA_HOME = 'PATH/TO/JAVE_HOME'

Done on OS X (10) hopefully this helps!